# Not being able to get attributes in the Image component in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just got the newest version of Unity 2017.3.0f3 and I don't get errors in my console but I get errors when I run a line of code such as this.  It was not like this in my previous version and everything worked fine.

[image]

actionBarImageComponent is a Image variable :

[image]

What is confusing to me is when I look at the component in the inspector I see areas where I should be able to do stuff like .material or .color to get the fields in the component but those options do not show up.  Am I missing something or is this a bug with the new Unity?  I noticed it wasn't just this script but others as well but I just wanted to link this one and maybe the solution here is a solution to the rest.

Imports :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

@Brandon Miller
When I do it the way I have done it I get this.
[image]
[image]

When I tried it the last way you mentioned I had success.
[image]

Thank you Brandon for helping me with my problem.

Go To Declaration : 
[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code is text, please post it as text. Ctrl-K will indent it automatically.

Comment: Can you not read it?

Comment: [Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/1663383)

Comment: @Draco18s You realize I have to show it this way to show my error right?  As if I linked code you wouldn't see the red "color".  Simplest way to display what is wrong.

Comment: The image is *helpful, yes* because of that, but it is still code. Some of us might want to *try and replicate it in our own environment* which would--in this case--require typing it all out by hand.

Comment: @Draco18s which is why it is only 1 line of code.  Do you happen to have a solution for this?

Comment: [Works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJcJF.png). Are you sure you've imported the right `Image` class? Do you see now why I might want your code posted as code? Particularly more than you've provided via a screenshot? Say...the whole class? Or at least enough of it to be a minimally complete, verified, example?

Comment: @Draco18s No not at all, all you really needed to know at this point is my imports and you have all the information you need.  I will edit to show my imports.  You really do not need to see anything more than what I showed.  If you still can get yours to work in the newest version of Unity then I need to reinstall it.

Comment: @JoeyL When you remove 'color' and put a '.', what does Intellisense show you? When you hover over the variable declaration, what namespace is Image coming from? Have you even tried to change the declaration to `private UnityEngine.UI.Image`? Also, what is the exact error message being produced, and possibly a stack trace?

Comment: @BrandonMiller You da man!  Sucks I will have to change my variables to this but I do hope there is something I can do where I don't have to go and change code.  Please mark as a solution and I will credit you.

Comment: When you remove 'color' and put a '.', what does Intellisense show you? When you hover over the variable declaration, what namespace is Image coming from? Have you even tried to change the declaration to private UnityEngine.UI.Image? Also, what is the exact error message being produced, and possibly a stack trace? - Answered in comments

Comment: @JoeyL Awesome! Glad I could help. That does kinda suck and is also a little weird, but I'm happy you got it solved!

Comment: Edited my original post to show the images you requested to display what is working.  Thank you again Brandon.

Comment: @JoeyL Those images are actually kind of interesting. It's definitely not the UnityEngine.UI.Image class that it is accessing. I'd bet you have a plugin installed that has an a global Image class that doesn't use Namespaces correctly, which is causing an ambiguous reference. Or maybe, somewhere along the line, you created your own Image class. Not sure.

Comment: I had a project that was used in a previous version of Unity and worked with no errors or warnings.  I put it into this newer version of Unity and I get these wonky errors.  Going to run more tests

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how reference ambiguity works at compile time.. From my experience it just chooses one and whichever one wins is the one you're stuck with lol

Comment: I did make a new project and I didn't have to use UnityEngine.UI.Image to get it to work.  So now I am really stumped.  I checked my project for anything with the words Image and didn't find anything with the same name for that conflict.

Comment: Added a screenshot of when I right click on Image and "Go To Declaration"

Comment: Someone was salty and tried to close this question lol. Can't blame haters for trying.